# How to access elements inside an array of objects in Javascript for a movieapp prototype

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, arrayobject

I've only shown the JS part of my code because the .html part only has one input box with name="my-input" inside a form.
What happens in this function is, if I enter 'Adventure' in my input box it gives me Edge of Tomorrow as the title of the movie and if I enter Romantic it gives me Lalaland likewise. Now what I want is,  shown in the movieList1() function i.e. I have two objects with same genre 'Adventure' for example, then I would want both the movie title, 'Edge of Tomorrow' and 'Dark Force' to be shown in my empty list with id 'here'. I want title of all the movies to be shown if the genre is similar but I'm able to only get one movie title at a time that is shown. I'm new to JS and object and array of objects looks a little confusing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
 function movieList(){
 //This function is called in an 'onkeyup' event inside the input box.
 var x = document.forms["my-form"]["my-input"].value; // x has what the user enters inside the 
 inputbox.
 const objList = [{
       title:'Edge of Tommorow',
       Genre: 'Adventure',
 },
 {
    title:'DarkForce',
    Genre: 'Tactical',
 },
 {
    title:'LalaLand',
    Genre:'Romantic'

 }];
  objList.forEach((ele,index) => {
 if(ele.Genre=='Adventure' && x==ele.Genre) {
    var ans = ele.title;
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans; // 'here' has the id of an empty <li></li> where 
   the title is shown.
    
 }
 else if(ele.Genre=='Tactical' && x==ele.Genre)
 {
    var ans = ele.title;
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans;
 }
 else if(ele.Genre=='Romantic' && x==ele.Genre)
 {
    var ans = ele.title;
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans;
 }
 else if(x=='')
 {
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML='';
 }

 });
 }

 function movieList1(){
 //This function is called in an 'onkeyup' event inside the input box.
 var x = document.forms["my-form"]["my-input"].value; // x has what the user enters inside the input 
 box.
 const objList = [{
       title:'Edge of Tommorow',
       Genre: 'Adventure',
 },
 {
    title:'DarkForce',
    Genre: 'Tactical, Adventure',
 },
 {
    title:'LalaLand',
    Genre:'Romantic,Tactical'

 }];
 objList.forEach((ele,index) => {
 if(ele.Genre=='Adventure' && x==ele.Genre) {
    var ans = ele.title;
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans; // 'here' has the id of an empty <li></li> where 
 the title is shown.
    
 }
 else if(ele.Genre=='Tactical' && x==ele.Genre)
 {
    var ans = ele.title;
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans;
 }
 else if(ele.Genre=='Romantic' && x==ele.Genre)
 {
    var ans = ele.title;
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans;
 }
 else if(x=='')
 {
    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML='';
 }

 });
 }
```

Comment: Could you more clear about the input-output:
For example --> Genre=='Tactical' then show (DarkForce, LalaLand) right?
I am focusing on the function movieList1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you want to do.

```
const objList = [{
    title: 'Edge of Tommorow',
    Genre: 'Adventure',
},
{
    title: 'DarkForce',
    Genre: 'Tactical',
},
{
    title: 'LalaLand',
    Genre: 'Adventure'

}];

let Gen = "Adventure";  // suppose this is from your input 
let temp = [];   // create an array to store all similar genre title

objList.forEach(x => {
    if (x.Genre == Gen) {
        temp.push(x.title);
    }
})
console.log(temp);
```

Output:

```
[ 'Edge of Tommorow', 'LalaLand' ]
```

you can also store objects in the temp array.

Comment: Could we do this for just an object? like var car = { model: 'Fiat' , price: 10000 }.. Could we loop through just an object too in the same way?

Comment: Yes you can @Narupo

Answer (score 0):

Thinking you are expecting the output like:: (Method movieList1)

1. for inputGenre=Tactical output will be DarkForce,LalaLand
2. for inputGenre=Adventure output will be Edge of Tommorow,DarkForce

```js
document.getElementById("txtGenre").addEventListener("keyup",searchMovies)

function searchMovies(){
let inputGenre=document.getElementById("txtGenre").value;
 const objList = [{
       title:'Edge of Tommorow',
       Genre: 'Adventure',
 },
 {
    title:'DarkForce',
    Genre: 'Tactical, Adventure',
 },
 {
    title:'LalaLand',
    Genre:'Romantic,Tactical'

 }];
 
let filterdData =objList.filter(r=>r.Genre.includes(inputGenre));

console.log(filterdData);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=filterdData.map(r=>r.Genre).join(",");
}
```

```css
#result{
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
Genre input: <input type="text" id="txtGenre" onClick="searchMovies"/>
<br/>
Output Movies List:
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There reason you are getting only one movie name is, you are **re-writing the HTML again** with the latest movie that matched the criteria each time forEach runs. You need to adjust your variables and how you assign your result to HTML.

Lets keep `ans` out of the loop, so it doesn't get overwrittern. And write to html at the end, after you have filtered all per your input.

```
var ans = [];
objList.forEach((ele,index) => {
 if(ele.Genre=='Adventure' && x==ele.Genre) {
    ans.push(ele.title);
 } else if(ele.Genre=='Tactical' && x==ele.Genre) {
    ans.push(ele.title);
 } else if(ele.Genre=='Romantic' && x==ele.Genre) {
    ans.push(ele.title);
 }
 // We dont need this
 // else if(x=='') {
 //    document.getElementById('here').innerHTML='';
 // }
 });
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans.join(', ');
```

At last, you join the answer using the in-built array function.

Now if you notice, your `if statements` are pretty much the same except for the *hardcoded genre*. So you could further refactor it.

```
var ans = [];
var genre = 'Adventure'; // assign your genre from input box here.
objList.forEach((ele,index) => {
  if (ele.Genre == genre && x==ele.Genre) {
    ans.push(ele.title);
  }
});
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = ans.join(', ');
```

Now you would have a single if statement which is easy to understand and modify.

Comment: You could use array.includes() method. objList.forEach(movie => {  if (movie.Genre.includes(genre)) ans.push(movie.title); })

Comment: Could we do this for just an object? like var car = { model: 'Fiat' , price: 10000 }.. Could we loop through just an object too in the same way?

Comment: You can read about for of and for in loops and decide for your requirement.

Comment: 'for of' and 'for in' loops are different kind of loops in JS.. can you provide me a good link if you have any?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of